# Can't fetch objects using QBCusomObjects off of main thread in android

Tags: android, quickblox

So in my app, I'm trying to fetch some custom objects I've made, and I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
            at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
            at com.quickblox.core.server.HttpRequestRunnable$1.<init>(HttpRequestRunnable.java:40)
            at com.quickblox.core.server.HttpRequestRunnable.<init>(HttpRequestRunnable.java:40)
            at com.quickblox.core.server.ThreadPoolIntentService.execute(ThreadPoolIntentService.java:23)
            at com.quickblox.core.server.HttpRequestTask.execute(HttpRequestTask.java:29)
            at com.quickblox.core.rest.RestRequest.asyncRequestWithCallback(RestRequest.java:110)
            at com.quickblox.core.query.Query.performInBgAsyncWithDelegate(Query.java:115)
            at com.quickblox.core.query.Query.performAsyncWithCallback(Query.java:218)
            at com.quickblox.customobjects.QBCustomObjects.getObjects(QBCustomObjects.java:532)
```

Originially, I was calling the getObjects method from a separate thread I spawned to do the network communication, both because doing it on the UI thread seemed like a bad idea, and because when I tried to do it on the UI thread I got a NetworkCommunicationOnMainThread exception.

Since the separate thread didn't work, I put the request in an AsyncTask to see if that would help, and it didn't change anything.

The code for the request is below

```
        final QBRequestGetBuilder requestBuilder = new QBRequestGetBuilder();

        try {
            Log.i(classTag, "Attempting to get UserID");
            requestBuilder.eq("User_ID", ""+ QBAuth.getSession().getUserId());
        } catch (QBResponseException e) {
            Log.e(classTag, "Failed to get UserID for current user");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        }

        QBCustomObjects.getObjects("Listing", requestBuilder, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<ArrayList<QBCustomObject>>() { ...}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This request works in a separate thread already

```
 QBCustomObjects.getObjects("Listing", requestBuilder, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<ArrayList<QBCustomObject>>() { ...}
```

so you don't need to wrap it

there is also a possibility to use 'sync' requests

Comment: If I put it on the UI thread however, I get a "NetworkOnMainThreadException". That was why I wrapped it in a separate thread.

Comment: I guess you wrapped sync version of method, not this one